# Why do I keep getting fake sign ups on my website?

Tags: website, hacking

I have a website and it is starting to get more users. To use the services offered by the site, a person has to sign up. The sign-up requires an email, password, and a five-number string for recapcha. To prevent bot-generated accounts, the form is timed. Recently I have noticed that some toofast sign-up attempts (1.5 seconds for example). These sign up attempts always enter info such as:

```
email: an valid email
password: How get online newbie from $9575 per day (just an example)
recapcha string: (missing)
```

These sign up attempts will certainly fail because of being faster than the minimal required seconds. Note that for these invalid sign ups, the website always shows a fake "success" page (instead of 404 or something). The purpose is to prevent the bots from keep guessing the security on this form.

My question: why do they (attackers? bots?) keep trying such sign up attempts? Because of showing a fake "success" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot developers don't care that much about failure scenarios, because there are much more different failure scenarios than success scenarios. "Supporting" each of the failure scenarios is more expensive than just letting them happen.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! Do you mean that I should display a 404 page and then bots might stop sending more invalid sign ups? What can be the benefits of keeping sending such unsuccessful sign ups?

Comment: I don't know how bots work, I haven't paid that much attention to those. This means, I don't know if bots stop sending invalid sign ups or not. From the bot developer point of view, it takes more time to handle each possible special case. Unless there is clear monetary benefit to do such handling, it is not implemented. Therefore it is more cost-effective for the bot operator to run simple bot without special case handling.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am just curious about why the bot keeps sending sign ups.

Comment: Because they have been implemented that way.

Comment: for what do they keep sending invalid unsuccessful sign ups? About 5 times a day.

Comment: They are trying to find if some sign up is correct, and then abuse your website in some way. They don't care about the unsuccesful ones because they cost practically nothing.